# Springmvc to raml document generation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want generate raml document using springmvc controller classes is there any already devloped source code exist or not if not ayone will please guide me how should i start it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, but the most popular is using SpringFox: https://github.com/springfox/springfox

It's able to generate both Swagger and RAML compatible documentations.

Comment: Thak you for your reply but i want to generate raml document from existing spring controller and i want source code for it and as per my research swagger is a tool to convert it into an API document as i am new to all these  thing will you please tell me which websites i should reffer